# Use IOC Container In ASP.NET Web Api 2

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, ioc-container, light-inject

i use LightInject(Light weight IOC Container in C#) in ExirRobot.Infrastructure as a global IOC Container Project in my solutionExplorer(Picture Was Attached).I want to register Ioc Config Class(IOC.cs) in ExirRobot.WebApi project inorder to inject Service Layer Interfaces(such as IArticleService) into web api controllers,how can i do this?

IOC.cs :

```cs
public class IOC{

     public static void Initialize()
     {
        var container = new LightInject.ServiceContainer();            
        //Engin Dependency Wiring
        container.Register<ISISearchResult, ISIContentProvider>(new PerRequestLifeTime());
        container.Register<ISearchArticleEngine, ISIEngineManager>(new PerRequestLifeTime());

        //Repository Dependency Wiring
        container.Register<IArticleRepository, ArticleRepository>(new PerRequestLifeTime());
        container.Register<IAuthorRepository, AuthorRepository>(new PerRequestLifeTime());
        container.Register<IIsiArticleDetailRepository, IsiArticleDetailRepository>(new PerRequestLifeTime());
        container.Register<IJournalRepository, JournalRepository>(new PerRequestLifeTime());
        container.Register<IVendorRepository, VendorRepository>(new PerRequestLifeTime());

        //Service Dependency Wiring
        container.Register<IArticleService, ArticleService>(new PerRequestLifeTime());
        container.Register<IAuthorService, AuthorService>(new PerRequestLifeTime());
        container.Register<IIsiArticleDetailService, IsiArticleDetailService>(new PerRequestLifeTime());
        container.Register<IJournalService, JournalService>(new PerRequestLifeTime());
        container.Register<IVendorService, VendorService>(new PerRequestLifeTime());
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an IDependencyResolver for LightInject or you can use this [NuGet package](http://www.lightinject.net/webapi/).

This is how you configure it into Web API:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

    // Other Web API configuration not shown.
}
```

See also [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

Comment: I don't have IDependencyResolver Implementation for LightInject now,and i wired dependencies in IOC.cs class in ExirRobot.Infrastructure project and i need to call Initialize method of IOC.cs in web api by Register(HttpConfiguration config) method in order to prevent extra wiring in Register method.in allover the Life Cycle of my application i have one IOC Container and i want to use it in Web Api project.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but in order to get DI to work with  ASP.NET Web API you need to use `IDependencyResolver` or `IHttpControllerFactory`. See Mark Seemann's [post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionandLifetimeManagementwithASP.NETWebAPI/) on the subject. So your IOC class might be okay, but you need an IDependencyResolver implementation to get it wired up with ASP.NET Web API.